# Which is better performance wise , map of map vs single map with keys concatenation?

Tags: java, performance, caching, dictionary, hashmap

I am implementing cache(obviously it has `get()` and `put()` methods) in Java. I have two String keys and one Object value.

`Key1 + Key2 --> Val` ('"Key1"+"Key2"' is the Key and Val is the cache value)

I have below two approaches to implement my cache with basic operations.

***Approach 1***:

Have single map, say `SingleMap<<Key`, `Value>>`, here Key is the concatenation of two keys (`Key1 + Key2`).

**Get Method signature**:

```
Val SingleMap.get(Key1 + Key2){ }
```

**Put Method signature**:

```
 void SingleMap.put(Key1 + Key2, val){ }
```

***Approach 2***:

Will use two maps

```
InnerMap<Key2, val>

OuterMap<Key1, InnerMap>
```

**Get Method Signature:**

```
Val OuterMap.get(Key1).get(key2){}
```

**Put Method Signature**:

```
Void OuterMap.put(Key1, new InnerMap(key2, val));
```

---

Which is the best approach(performance-wise) to implement cache ?
If you have any other better approach, please let me know.

Comment: You might not notice much of a difference in terms of performance (did you try something?) but from a memory point of view the first approach might be better, depending on how big the outer keyset would be (i.e. how many inner maps you'd end up with). Besides that if both keys have to be provided in any case the question would be why there are two anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, your first approach would be faster, as it only has to get the information out of 1 map.
If you're using this method however, you have to make sure that the keys will allways remain in the same order (key1 can never be key2), otherwise you'll have to add key1+key2 and key2+key1 to the map.

More information about performance with collections: http://bigocheatsheet.com/